# How to check persistent storage?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, persistent-storage

I think I'm being completely stupid but....

I want to check if some of the data has been stored correctly in persistent storage. In the simulator (I don't have an iPhone), I'm currently killing the app, then Xcode throws me an error (rightly so) and I can't reopen the app afterwards. Is there another way of checking the persistent storage?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: put in a little test function to read the data as soon as you have written it, but more importantly, add some error trapping to where you're trying to read it - you shouldn't crash the app because of missing data

Comment: Sorry I was being quite confusing. I've edited by question, but I'm killing my app and then I can't reopen it on the simulator, which is how I would check everything has stored correctly etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a real device you can download the contents of the app's folder using Xcode:

1. Window --> Devices
2. Select your Device
3. Select your app
4. Click the gear icon --> Download Container

The downloaded container will have all the contents stored on the filesystem in your apps folder.

If you are using the simulator you can use a tool like [SimPholders](https://simpholders.com) to find the app folder on your mac.

If you saved something into `UserDefaults` you have to look for a file named `<bundleIdentifier>.plist`. That file will contain all the `UserDefaults` for your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot @naglerrr, it's quite tedious to do this every time. There should be a way to kill an app and then reopen on the simulator...

Comment: There is. Just click Run or CMD + R in Xcode. This will kill your app (not the simulator) and re-run it afterwards.